# How to get data from nested JSON in Java Android

Tags: java, android, json, nested

I need to get info for my app from an API. Problem is the API response is a JSON with the following format:

```html
{
   "jsonapi":{
      "data":[
         {
            "id":"id_id",
            "name":{
               "en":"nombre en ingles",
               "es":"nombre en español"
            },
            "company":{
               "id":"id_company",
               "name":"nombre company"
            },
            "city":{
               "id":"id_city",
               "name":{
                  "en":"nombre en ingles ciudad",
                  "es":"nombre en español ciudad"
               }
            },
            "province":{
               "id":"id_province",
               "name":{
                  "en":"nombre en ingles provincia",
                  "es":"nombre en español provincia"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"id_id2",
            "name":{
               "en":"nombre en ingles 2",
               "es":"nombre en español 2"
            },
            "company":{
               "id":"id_company 2",
               "name":"nombre company 2"
            },
            "city":{
               "id":"id_city 2",
               "name":{
                  "en":"nombre en ingles ciudad 2",
                  "es":"nombre en español ciudad 2"
               }
            },
            "province":{
               "id":"id_province 2",
               "name":{
                  "en":"nombre en ingles provincia 2",
                  "es":"nombre en español provincia 2"
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "id":"id_id 3",
            "name":{
               "en":"nombre en ingles 3",
               "es":"nombre en español 3"
            },
            "company":{
               "id":"id_company 3",
               "name":"nombre company 3"
            },
            "city":{
               "id":"id_city",
               "name":{
                  "en":"nombre en ingles ciudad 3",
                  "es":"nombre en español ciudad 3"
               }
            },
            "province":{
               "id":"id_province 3",
               "name":{
                  "en":"nombre en ingles provincia 3",
                  "es":"nombre en español provincia 3"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "city":{
      "latitude":"-333",
      "longitude":"111"
   }
}
```

The only way I know to get info from a JSON is with JSONObject, but if I do 
`object.getString("name")` what do I get? Cause "name" property is everywhere.
Is it possible to do something like `object.getString("data").getString("name")`? But if so, I still have the same problem cause inside data there are lots of "name" properties.

Is there any way to get an specific property when there are JSON inside others JSON? If so, how?

I'm not sure this can be done with GSON, I'm new in Android, this is for a project for my studies, I barely know how to use JSONObject and JSONArray, so please, I'm lost! I need some help, at least to know if this is possible.

Thank you in advance!!! :)

Comment: JSON is not valid can you share valid JSON

Comment: Build the pojo using some plugin or online sites like [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) (because it is easier and takes less time) than use [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to simply map your data. That is how I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'name' value that you'll get will depend on how you are querying the JsonObject. You can read about the JsonObject definition and the query structure here https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Here's a quick stub on how you can retrieve specific property values from your example JSON.

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(json_data_in_a_string);
JSONObject jsonAPI = mainObject.getJSONObject("jsonapi");
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)jsonAPI.get("data");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject childObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = childObject.getString("id");

    JSONObject name = childObject.getJSONObject("name");
    String name_en= name.getString("en");
    String name_es = name.getString("es");

    JSONObject company = childObject.getJSONObject("company");
    String company_id = company.getString("id");
    String company_name = company.getString("name");

}
```

You can also create POJO's to easily read values from the JSON. There are several tools available online on how to generate pojo classes, validate json, etc.

Here are few that I use -

http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

Here the whole document is `JSONObject` which has a key-pair value with name `jsonapi` which is having a value of nested `JSONObject`.
Get the `JSONObject` with name `jsonapi`

```
JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) obj;
JSONObject jsonApi = (JSONObject)jo.get("jsonapi");
```

Then this `JSON` object has a key-pair value with key `data` which holds `array of JSON objects`.

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)jsonAoi.get("data");
```

Now you can `iterate` the array to get each `JSONObject` of the `JSONArray` and form each object you can get your value such as `name`, `city`, `company`.

Answer (score 0):

First parse your Json Properly and check if it is correct using :

https://jsonlint.com/

Later Create POJO or Model class for your json parsing from:

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/

Than Use Gson for parsing the Json :

```
ResponseData response = gson.fromJson(jsonString, ResponseData.class);
```

than you can access any value from response.

*I didnt showed the basic Json parsing using JsonArray and JsonObject as your json is very much nested. So its better to use Gson*